# How to show negative values different color in column chart?

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

Is it possible that in a column chart like [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/Pfuk6/), we can have the negative values show red color?

```
"data": [
    {
        "label": "Week 1",
        "value": "14.5"
    }, 
    {
        "label": "Week 2",
        "value": "-6.5"
    },
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/Pfuk6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some [useful documentation on highlighting specific data here](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/tutorials/highlight-specific-data-points-on-chart.html).

You'll need to specify a color attribute on specific data points.

```
"data": [
    {
        "label": "Week 1",
        "value": "14.5"
    }, 
    {
        "label": "Week 2",
        "value": "-6.5",
        "color": "#ff0000"
    }, 
    //...
]
```

One thing that may help you to handle this is the [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function:

```
var theData = [
    {
        "label": "Week 1",
        "value": "14.5"
    }, 
    {
        "label": "Week 2",
        "value": "-6.5"
    }
];

// Magic is here:
theData.forEach(function(val) {
    if (val.value < 0) {         
        val.color = "#ff0000";
    }
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4t48haxL/)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `displayValue` attribute:

```
"data": [
    {
        "label": "Week 1",
        "displayValue": '<font style="color:black;">14.5</font>', 
        "value": "14.5"
    }, 
    {
        "label": "Week 2",
        "displayValue": '<font style="color:red;">-6.5</font>', 
        "value": "-6.5"
    },
```